# Need help to understand service bus message unit?

Tags: azureservicebus

I use two Premium service bus namespaces in my subscription with capacity 1 and I am getting a monthly bill like "54 message units is charged at X amount of $". I am curious how azure calculates number of message units my services spent. If there is a calculation that given throughput of 10k requests/second, it is translated this number of message units, then it will help me predict cost. Any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: If you're using 2 premium namespaces with capacity of 1 MU each, you should not be billed for 54 MUs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Premium Tier is a dedicated offer, you are billed per messaging unit an hourly rate and not for number of operations you process. Doesn't matter if you do 10 or 10K messages per second. Number of operations matters on a standard tier. And it's hard to say how many messages per second it translates into as there's no commitment to a specific throughput on the standard tier and performance is not guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks Sean, my understand of your writing is that if service bus is used for two hours, then two message units are spent, cost will be 2 MUs x MU hourly rate. But then looking at my subscription spend report, why are there only 54 MUs in last month? Looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-pricing-billing, it says "A single workload or entity can span multiple messaging units and the number of messaging units can be changed at will, although billing is in 24-hour or daily rate charges." So maybe it is charged at daily rate?

Comment: Ha, it is daily https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/service-bus/ says "$22.26 fixed rate per message unit". So, does that mean if service used service bus for 5 minutes, it will be counted as 1 message unit that day?

Comment: The cost is per hour. Documentation is stale 
I blogged about it [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/what-you-pay-is-what-you-get). There's no per minute charge. Which wouldn't make sense either in most of scenarios  Per hour charge is great as it allows scenarios such as testing w/o racking up a cost for the whole day.